# Add "/" symbol after second character

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have Xamarin TextInput. It's some kind of 'mm/yy' format. I need to insert `/` after second symbol.

I have this method for adding `/` after 2 character

```
private static string AppendAtPosition(string baseString, int position, string character)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(baseString);
    for (int i = position; i < sb.Length; i += (position + character.Length))
        sb.Insert(i, character);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And I call it like this

```
ExpiresInput.EditingChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    var creditcardyear = ExpiresInput.Text;

    if (creditcardyear.Length <= 2) return;
    if (creditcardyear.Length > 2)
    {
        ExpiresInput.Text = AppendAtPosition(creditcardyear, 2, "/");
    }
    if (creditcardyear.Length == 5) {
        return;
    }
```

But when I want to insert `22/12` for example I have this.

[image]

How I can fix this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `creditcardyear.Insert(2, "/");` make 22/12 to 22//12 @Amy

Comment: Because it already has a `/`, you don't need to insert one.  So check for a `/` first.

Comment: It helps. Thank's @Amy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ExpiresInput.EditingChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    var currentText = ExpiresInput.Text;
    if (currentText.Length == 1)
        return;

    int strLength = currentText.Length;
    if (Char.IsDigit(currentText, strLength - 1) && Char.IsDigit(currentText, strLength - 2))
      currentText = $"{currentText}/";
}
```

This code adds "/" after every two-digit character. You need to remove last "/" after you are sure that you do not type any other character to textbox.